# Get syscall number at runtime in Python

Tags: python, linux, system-calls, libc

I've got some code that needs to call the `getrandom` libc function, but if it's not available (as it isn't on glibc versions before 2.24), I need to fall back to invoking the syscall directly. Unfortunately, the syscall number for the `getrandom` syscall differs by kernel version and platform, and my code needs to run on multiple platforms.

Is there a way that I can get the number at runtime?

Comment: this doesn't make any sense

Comment: You should not have to resort to making direct `syscall` calls. Ever.

Comment: I assure you I do or I wouldn't have asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [os.urandom()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) or [random.SystemRandom()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom)

Comment: Unfortunately I need the `getrandom` syscall in particular because I need to pass it particular flags.